# I get an error that says cannot implicitly convert string type to int.

Tags: c#, xml, progress-bar

I have an xml Nodelist with a child node named "Rating" the rating is of int type

```
progressBar1.Value = xList[0].ChildNodes[1].FirstChild.Value;
```

How do I use the ToString method here?
I tried putting it at the end of the line but it still doesnt work

Comment: Your `progressbar1.Value` must be an `int` type. You need to use `Convert.ToInt32()` for the XML node value.

Answer (score 4):

[`ProgressBar.Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.value) property is `int` but [`XmlNode.Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.value) returns `string`. And as error pointed, there is no implicit conversation from `string` to `int`.

*If* this `XmlNode.Value` value is a valid integer, you need to parse it to integer with [`Int32.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse) method like;

```
progressBar1.Value = Int32.Parse(xList[0].ChildNodes[1].FirstChild.Value);
```